# MySQL: query joined to list of dates, but how do I display multiple entries per date

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like (I've tried to strip out non-relevant fields/joins for clarity):

```
SET @num = -1;
SELECT 
*,
CAST(DATE_ADD( '2012-04-01', interval @num := @num+1 day)AS DATE) AS date_sequence, 
DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2012-04-01', interval @num+1 day)) AS day_week
FROM batch AS b1

left join (
select
batch.`startedDate` AS batch_startedDate,
epiRun.`runType` AS epiRun_runType
.... other fields selected.........
from batch
left join `epiRun` epiRun ON epiRun.`batchID`= batch.`keyID`
.......other joins........
WHERE batch.`startedDate` >= '2012-04-01' AND batch.`startedDate` <= '2012-04-18' 
ORDER BY  batch.`startedDate`ASC) 
AS b2 ON cast((b2.`batch_startedDate`) AS DATE)=CAST(DATE_ADD('2012-04-01', interval @num+1
day)AS DATE)

WHERE
(DATE_ADD('2012-04-01', interval @num+1 day) <= '2012-04-18')
```

The nested select query performs as I expect when run by itself.  This query has a couple of problems:

-Every field in from the batch table is selected, but since this is for an iReport it's not too much of a problem

-I get the list of dates from 1st April to 18th April, but if I have multiple batches on a day then I only get one displayed - ideally I'd like multiple identical entries in the date column with a unique entry for each batch.  It is important that I can see when there are days with no batches.

Example of table I have:

```
Date          Batch
01/04/2012    TS01
02/04/2012    TS03
03/04/2012    null
```

and what I'd like to generate:

```
Date          Batch
01/04/2012    TS01
01/04/2012    TS02
02/04/2012    TS03
02/04/2012    TS04
03/04/2012    null
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would create a separate "dates" table and populate it with all the dates from say 1/1/2000 through 12/31/2050 (or whatever date range will cover all potential queries) and then do a left join from that table to the batch and epiRun tables.

I think that this is a much cleaner way to do what you are looking for and will give you exactly the results you desire.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have write access to the database but I'll ask that the date table be added and see how I get on.